# Problem with making file upload in a Razor Pages form optional

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

[Relevant code here](https://github.com/Atulin/Ogma/tree/master/Ogma3/Pages/MyStories)

Both `Create` and `Edit` pages contain a form for creating a new story. In that form, there's a field that lets the user upload a cover image.

My intention is to make that cover image optional, hence the lack of a `[Required]` annotation on the relevant `IFormFile` field in my [`InputModel`](https://github.com/Atulin/Ogma/blob/master/Ogma3/Pages/MyStories/Edit.cshtml.cs#L76-L79)

When a file is supplied, everything is perfectly fine. However, when no file is supplied, `ModelState` becomes invalid, and [logging the errors](https://github.com/Atulin/Ogma/blob/master/Ogma3/Pages/MyStories/Edit.cshtml.cs#L200-L209) prints

```
object does not implement IFormFile interface
object does not implement IFormFile interface
```

to the console.

I assume that's because `Cover` in `InputModel` is `null`, and `null` does not implement `IFormFile`. The issue itself seems simple, but I can't come up with a proper solution.

I could check the `ModelState` errors in advance, and if the only error is `object does not implement IFormFile interface` let the code go through, but it seems like an incredibly hacky solution.